# How to use IP addresses to populate a webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, ip, webbrowser-control

I have a listbox containing IP addresses - I want to select one from that list and load the corresponding web page.  For some reason it doesn't treat the IP as a valid parameter.

```
        ' LBPrinters contains a list of IP addresses i.e. 192.168.101.45
        Dim url As String = Trim(LBPrinters.SelectedItem.ToString)
        Try
            WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Exception: Did not work")
        End Try
```

Comment: `For some reason it doesn't treat the IP as a valid parameter`, can you explain in further details?

Comment: Do you have a Http service listening on port 80 in the machine `192.168.101.45` (local network, assuming it's not an example)? Did you prefix the IP address with `Http://`? Build a URL, with `Uri()` or `UriBuilder()` (pick the latter, e.g., `dim builder as UriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http", "192.168.101.45")`, then take `builder.Uri`).

Comment: As in the example above, when calling with a string variable: is url ="192.168.102.103" the call fails, but making the call with a string literal opens the page. (IP is a fake example; I'm using a known good IP in my network)

Comment: As it turns out, bringing in the IP from a listbox appended some sort of character on the right end.  I modified the contents of the listbox to be comma-delimited (to include description of the IP destination ie <IP>,<description>) and used .split to place the components into a string array - then using the string array(0), prepending "http://" and appending "/" as the parameter for WebBrowser and it worked.